# How to correctly nest psmatrix within psmatrix (without undesired space)

Tags: beamer, pstricks, psmatrix

I'd like to nest several psmatrix environments within a `psmatrix`, so that every cell of the outer `psmatrix` itself is an psmatrix again. Ultimately I want to draw within these inner matrices using `pspicture`. All that in a `beamer` document in case this is relevant.
Unfortunately when nesting the psmatrices, so unwanted space is added in a way, that the outer `psmatrix` is not longer properly centered with respect to the page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand\mycirc{\pspicture(.5,.5)\pscircle(.25,.25){.25}\endpspicture}
\newcommand\myframe{\pspicture(.5,.5)\psframe(.5,.5)\endpspicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Properly centered}
\begin{center}
 \begin{psmatrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D
 \end{psmatrix}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Not centered}
\begin{center}
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]A1&A2\\A3&A4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]B1&B2\\B3&B4\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]C1&C2\\C3&C4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]D1&D2\\D3&D4\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Not centered - pspicture example}
\begin{center}
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My question is how to make the psmatrix being correctly aligned. I'm mentioning the `pspicture` environment here just in case someone has a much more elegant solution for this.
Note: As a workaround I'm using a not nested `psmatrix` where the distance between the four "blocks" is introduced by additional empty columns. Please don't propose that. I'd prefer the embedded solution this it allows more fine-grained positioning.

Thanks in advance to all of you who spend their time on giving me some hints!

### Edit by The Last Error

The following edit tries to simplify the given MWE above. Feel free to rollback if you don't like my edit.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand\mycirc{\pspicture(.5,.5)\pscircle(.25,.25){.25}\endpspicture}
\newcommand\myframe{\pspicture(.5,.5)\psframe(.5,.5)\endpspicture}

\begin{document}
\section{Properly centered}
\begin{center}
 \begin{psmatrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D
 \end{psmatrix}
 \end{center}

\section{Not centered}
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2,mcol=l]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]A1&A2\\A3&A4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]B1&B2\\B3&B4\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]C1&C2\\C3&C4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]D1&D2\\D3&D4\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}}
 \end{center}

\section{Not centered - pspicture example}
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Is there an ulterior reason it has to be a `psmatrix`?  There are many other ways to set up row/column formats.

Comment: Of course there are other ways to do this. The way I know is pstricks/psmatrix and I like this way due to the features of drawing node connections and bonds (specifically required, but skipped for MWE). If you have an easier way then let's have it!

Answer (score 1):

The OP insisted in the comments that alternative approaches (not employing `psmatrix`) were *not* what he was looking for.  And I have not debugged the nesting of "psmatrices".  Furthermore, my attempts are stymied by the fact that `\pspicture` always produces blank images, no matter what MWE I run.

BE THAT AS IT MAY, one can simply add a negative `\kern` when entering the outer `psmatrix` and everything else flows from there.  Experimentation with the MWE indicates that the magnitude of the kern should equal the value of `colsep` of the outer `psmatrix`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand\mycirc{\pspicture(.5,.5)\pscircle(.25,.25){.25}\endpspicture}
\newcommand\myframe{\pspicture(.5,.5)\psframe(.5,.5)\endpspicture}

\begin{document}
\section{Properly centered}
\begin{center}
 \begin{psmatrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D
 \end{psmatrix}
 \end{center}

\section{Not centered}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\kern-2cm%
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2,mcol=l]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]A1&A2\\A3&A4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]B1&B2\\B3&B4\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]C1&C2\\C3&C4\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]D1&D2\\D3&D4\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}}
 \end{center}

\section{Not centered - pspicture example}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\kern-2cm% WITHOUT A VISUAL, DON'T KNOW IF AMOUNT IS CORRECT
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=2]
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}\\
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\mycirc&\mycirc\\ \mycirc&\mycirc\end{psmatrix}&
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]\myframe&\myframe\\ \myframe&\myframe\end{psmatrix}
  \end{psmatrix}}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to use a nested `psmatrix`. It can simply be done without it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{centered}
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
 \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]
  A1&A2  &&& B1&B2 \\
  A3&A4  &&& B3&B4 \\[1cm]
  C1&C2  &&& D1&D2 \\
  C3&C4  &&& D3&D4
\end{psmatrix}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]